# Disabling trackpad for Lenovo thinkpad W541

Tags: touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I'm trying to disable the trackpad for the Lenovo ThinkPad W541 running Windows 7 I got at work because I would rather use a USB mouse. There is no simple checkbox and I can't even access the Lenovo Proprietary Software that I think they have in place. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: In 'Bios' see if ps/2+touchpad is enabled  if not  enable and retry

Comment: that worked. I'll post it as an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, go to BIOS in your system. You can access this by pressing enter upon startup. then scroll to config, then trackpad, then disable. Then press f10 to save and exit. The trackpad should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I've got several W541s in my office that are exhibiting behavior of the trackpad being on, even though it's turned off on the BIOS.  Users hate it because any time they type something, the cursor jumps around and "senses" a click when there is no click being performed.  As a result, typing is an infuriating act.  Reboot the machine and the trackpad stays off for an hour so, but re-enables itself.  Any time the BIOS is checked, it is verfied that the Trackpad is DISABLED.  Lenovo needs to issue a BIOS update in order to take care of this.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this after my partner wiped some dorps of the keyboard. 
I could not believe that messed up the touchpad hardware.

And it did not, it turns out she pressed a shortcut.
Lenovo support [states](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/videos/vid100752):

> Some Lenovo and IdeaPads, along with some ThinkPads, also have a dedicated keyboard shortcut to enable or disable the touchpad.

E.g. on a Lenovo [Ideapad Z400](https://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/6645/how-to-enable-the-touchpad-on-a-lenovo-ideapad-z400):

> On the keyboard, the keys that are used to enable or disable the touchpad is the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.